# Cloudhopper SMPP - how to change logging options

Tags: logging, bind, smpp

I'd like to know if it is possible to change the logging settings for Cloudhopper so sensitive login information is not logged upon each Bind operation?

Hope it's an easy one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [solution](https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp/issues/26) .

> ```
> LoggingOptions loggingOptions = new LoggingOptions();
> loggingOptions.setLogPdu(false);
> csSmppConfig.setLoggingOptions(loggingOptions);
> ```